# Preview Image Clear

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm doing image upload.Here I added preview image on click 'X' cancel button div is removed then if we upload next time div have to come.
I tried but not getting after removing image div on next time image div is not coming.Is there another easy way to do this?
can anyone suggest me?
help will be appreciated.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#selectedFile').change(function () {
     var a = $('#selectedFile').val().toString().split('\\');
     $('#fileInput').val(a[a.length -1]);
 });
 function readURL(input) {

   if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
     var reader = new FileReader();

     reader.onload = function(e) {
       $('#img').attr('src', e.target.result);
       $('#img').hide();
       $('#img').fadeIn(650);

     }
     reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
   }
 }

 $("#selectedFile").change(function() {
   readURL(this);
 });
 $('.clear_img_btn').click(function(){
  $('.img_contain').fadeOut(300);
 });

}):
```

```css
#btn_image {
    padding: 10px;
    border-radius: 0px 8px 8px 0px;
    background: linear-gradient(-80deg, #1B325F, #226296);
    color: #ffffff;
}
#selectedFile {
    position: absolute;
    left: 39%;
    opacity: 0;
}
img#img {
 width: 25%; 
 height: 75px;
}
.of_input {
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: column;
 justify-content: flex-end;
 flex-basis: 61%;
}
.iva_of_upload { flex-basis:40%; }
.img_contain {position: relative;}
.img_contain a.clear_img_btn {
 position: absolute;
    left: 20%;
    bottom: 1%;
    padding: 1%;
    text-decoration: none;
    border: 1px solid #006799;
    background: linear-gradient(-80deg, #1B325F, #226296);
    color: #ffffff;
 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <div class="of_input">
    <div class="iva_of_upload">
      <input type='file' id="selectedFile" />
      <input type="text" id="fileInput" />
      <span onclick="document.getElementById('selectedFile').click();" id="btn_image">Upload</span>
    </div>
      <div class='img_contain'>
        <img id="img" align='middle' alt="" title=''/>
        <a href="#" class="clear_img_btn">x</a>
      </div> 
    </div>
```

Comment: you fade out (and thus hide) ".img_contain" but never fade it in again. Since "#img" is within ".img_contain" it remains hidden as long as ".img_contain" is faded out. Make sure you're doing the fading in and out on the same elements.

Comment: thnks. like this m tried not working $('.clear_img_btn').click(function(){
  $('.img_contain').fadeOut(300);
  $('btn_image').click( function(){
   $('.img_contain').fadeIn(300);
  });
 });

Comment: I was thinking actually wouldn't it be better to just fade out "#img" instead? Since you already fade it in during the reader onload event?

Comment: Is there any alternate way to do this.

Comment: I've just suggested it. I don't understand why any other elements need to be involved. That way, you fade out the image when the "clear" button is pressed, and if a new image is selected, it fades in again. Likewise if the "upload" button is pressed you could program it to fade out the "#img" tag after the upload completes.